# How to Add Data From MS Access 2016 Query to SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to transfer Data directly using a query from an Access table to an SQL table ?
I have in mind something like that:

```
INSERT INTO tableTSQL
SELECT * 
FROM tableAccess2016
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Yes. Why not just try it? tableTSQL would be a linked table.

Comment: Without specifying field names, fields in both table must be in exact same order in table design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "ODBC;APP=Microsoft Access;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLDEV03;DATABASE=Database_Test;NETWORK=DBMSSOCN;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=Yes;"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandTimeout = 180

cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

cmd.Execute
```

I am using similar code every day for tables I do not want to link to Access.